# how to get the indexes of all the occurences of words in string?

Tags: android, string, indexing

I want to get indexes of all the occurences of string_to_be_search

Input:

```
String line="hello this is prajakta , how are you?? hello this is prajakta!"
String text_to_search= "hello this is prajakta"
```

Here the occurrences of text_to_search is 2 so  I need list of starting indexes

Output:

```
List l=[0,39]
```

Also  I have tried  a code below

```
 public List getIndexesOfMultipleOccuredString(String originalString,String textToSearch) {
    int i, last = 0, count = 0;
    List l = new ArrayList();
    do {
        i = originalString.indexOf(textToSearch, last);
        if (i != -1) l.add(i);
        last = i + textToSearch.length();
    } while (i != -1);
    return l;
}
```

BUT 
if my input is as follows

```
String line="hello this is prajakta ,i love to drive car and i am a carpainter"
String text_to_search="car"
```

Output:

```
It gives me two indexes as carpainter contains car which i don't want
Output should be [39]
```

Comment: What kind of solutions have you tried so far where the second scenario does not work as you would like?

Comment: @SCCC i have added my code

Comment: @zums: Please don't modify code posted by OP. It creates confusion and problems.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I could not able modify directly the code. First it get reviewed.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 you mean the output which posted above is correct for input??

Comment: Thats incorrect. I agree but you answer to that not edit it. or ask OP for clarification via comment.

Comment: @PrajaktaParkhade Please correct your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it using regex(word matching)

```
String line= "hello this is prajakta , how are you?? hello this is prajakta!";
String text_to_search = "\\bhello this is prajakta\\b";
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(text_to_search);
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

while (m.find()) {
    list.add(m.start());
}

Log.i("All occurrences", "values are " + list.toString());
```

**Output:** `[0, 39]`

If you search using these strings

```
String line="hello this is prajakta ,i love to drive car and i am a carpainter";
String text_to_search="car";// use as "\\bcar\\b"
```

**Output** `[40]`